# How do I set the cookie expiration for MojoX::Sessions?

Tags: perl, session-cookies, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

Whatever expiration value that I give to `expires()` or `expires_delta()`, the cookie expiration is always one hour.  How do I change it so that the session and the cookie expiration times match?

Comment: Please show us the actual code you're having problems with.

Comment: $session->expires(time + 3600 * 8)

Answer (score 3):

Although I like vti's work, that distribution looks outdated and was replaced in the past. Today the standard way to set session expire dates is explained in [Mojolicious::Sessions](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Sessions#default_expiration):

> ### default_expiration
>
> ```
> my $time  = $sessions->default_expiration;
> $sessions = $sessions->default_expiration(3600);
> ```
>
> Default time for sessions to expire in seconds from now, defaults to
>   `3600`. The expiration timeout gets refreshed for every request. Setting the value to 0 will allow sessions to persist until the browser window
>   is closed, this can have security implications though. For more
>   control you can also use the `expiration` and `expires` session values.
>
> ```
> # Expiration date in epoch seconds from now (persists between requests)
> $c->session(expiration => 604800);
>
> # Expiration date as absolute epoch time (only valid for one request)
> $c->session(expires => time + 604800);
>
> # Delete whole session by setting an expiration date in the past
> $c->session(expires => 1);
> ```

I wrote a small test script to make sure it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Time::Local 'timegm';

# set some session variable
get '/test' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->session(
        expires => timegm(0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 142), # star wars day '42
        foo     => 42,
    );
    $self->render_text('foo is set');
};

use Test::More;
use Test::Mojo;
use Mojo::Cookie::Response;
my $t = Test::Mojo->new;

$t->get_ok('/test')->status_is(200)->content_is('foo is set');
my $cookies = Mojo::Cookie::Response->parse($t->tx->res->headers->set_cookie);
is $cookies->[0]->expires, 'Sun, 04 May 2042 00:00:00 GMT', 'right expire time';

done_testing;
```

Output:

```
ok 1 - get /test
ok 2 - 200 OK
ok 3 - exact match for content
ok 4 - right expire time
1..4
```